# Algorithm to generate subsets satisfying binary relation

Tags: python, algorithm, subset

I am looking for a reasonable algorithm in python (well, because I have rather complicated mathematical objects implemented in python, so I cannot change the language) to achieve the following:

> I am given a reflexive, symmetric binary relation `bin_rel` on a set `X`. The requested function `maximal_compatible_subsets(X, bin_rel)` should return all containmentwise maximal subsets of X such that the binary relation holds for all pairs a,b of elements in X.

In some more detail: Suppose I am given a binary relation on a set of objects, say

```
def bin_rel(elt1,elt2):
    # return True if elt1 and elt2 satisfy the relation and False otherwise
    # Example: set intersection, in this case, elt1 and elt2 are sets
    # and the relation picks those pairs that have a nonempty intersection
    return elt1.intersection(elt2)
```

I can also assume that the relation `bin_rel` is **reflexive** (this is, `binary_rel(a,a) is True` holds) and **symmetric** (this is, `binary_rel(a,b) is binary_rel(b,a)` holds).

I am now given a set `X` and a function `bin_rel` as above and seek an efficient algorithm to obtain the desired subsets of `X`

For example, in the case of the set intersection above (with sets replaced by lists for easier reading):

```
> X = [ [1,2,3], [1,3], [1,6], [3,4], [3,5], [4,5] ]
> maximal_compatible_subsets(X,bin_rel)
[[[1,2,3],[1,3],[1,6]], [[1,2,3],[1,3],[3,4],[3,5]], [[3,4],[3,5],[4,5]]]
```

This problem doesn't seem to be very exotic, so most welcome would be a pointer to an efficient existing snippet of code.

Comment: The intersection was just a simple example. In general, I am given ``bin_rel``, so I do not worry how this code is written. Also, I can assume it to be reflexive and symmetric, and I do not need to test that. But this assumption will certainly influence the algorithm as I do not ever need to test ``bin_rel(a,a)`` or (both ``bin_rel(a,b)`` and ``bin_rel(b,a)``).

Comment: Note that this is NP-hard, since you can use it to solve max-clique: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem

Comment: @MattTimmermans: yep, that's right!

Comment: You could use [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html)

Comment: @MattTimmermans: Now as you write this, indeed what that algorithm searches for is exactly the set of all maximal cliques (or maximal independent sets) in a graph.

Comment: @niemmi: That seems to do the job perfectly! Put it as an answer, I use and test it for my problem, and except your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Matt Timmermans noted this is [finding maximal cliques problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Maximal_versus_maximum) that can be solved by [Bron–Kerbosch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm). NetworkX has [implementation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html) that can be used for Python.

Comment: Note that it is not the maximal clique problem, as there only one clique (of globally maximal size) is requested, while I was requesting all maximal cliques. Anyway, thanks, and ``networkx.find_cliques`` does exactly that.

Comment: @ChristianStump: Sorry if I was unclear, I reworded the answer a bit to make it clearer. Finding maximal cliques is indeed different problem than finding maximum clique.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use python straight out of the box, you could use the following as a starting point:

```
from itertools import combinations

def maximal_compatible_subsets(X, bin_rel):
    retval = []
    for i in range(len(X) + 1, 1, -1):
        for j in combinations(X, i):
            if all(bin_rel(a, b) for a, b in combinations(j, 2)) and not any(set(j).issubset(a) for a in retval):
                retval.append(tuple(j))
    return tuple(retval)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = ( (1,2,3), (1,3), (1,6), (3,4), (3,5), (4,5) )

    def nonempty_intersection(a, b):
        return set(a).intersection(b)

    print x
    print maximal_compatible_subsets(x, nonempty_intersection)
```

Outputs:

```
((1, 2, 3), (1, 3), (1, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5))
(((1, 2, 3), (1, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5)), ((1, 2, 3), (1, 3), (1, 6)), ((3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)))
```